# Instagram Feed for public content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, instagram-api

I need to create a rails api, which outputs a custom json that is instagram and twitter feed for a certain hashtag. But instagram does not allow me to display content when my app is in sandbox mode, when i try to submit my app for review it is says my use case is not supported for a 'one-off' project. (which is completely stupid!)

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).

Does anyone know of any alternative company that offers this kind of service, or is there a workaround of this?

Comment: I am currently building that exact application which allows you to subscribe to an hashtag, retrieve the images from the instagram API and moderate the incoming media to display in a plugin. If you're interested I could set you up as a Beta tester.

Comment: Yes please that would be great!

Comment: @dennis I would also be interested.

Comment: As of November, 2017, Instagram stopped taking new application review submissions for public_content scope permission. There are 3rd party providers who provide json feed of Instagram posts using the Instagram permission that they already received. Most of them are very costly. I found https://www.socialmediawall.io that looks the best.